# Does group $G$ of order 42 have a normal cyclic subgroup of order 21?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Show that a group $G$ of order 42 has a normal cyclic subgroup of order 21.

What I did so far is using Sylow's theorem to show that $G$ has a unique 7-sylow subgroup $S(7)$ (which is normal) and {1 or 7} of 3-sylow subgroup $S(3)$. If $n_3$ (the number of $S(3)$) is 1, Then $H:=S(7) \times S(3)$ is normal and also cyclic. However, the problem occurs when $n_3 = 7$. In this case, now $H$ can be written as the semi-direct product, namaly $S(3) \rtimes_\phi S(7)$.
My question is **how to show this $H = S(3) \rtimes_\phi S(7)$ is also cyclic?** Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't this a counterexample: Take any non-cyclic group $H$ order 21 and consider $G = H\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In fact, there is [just one](http://world.std.com/~jmccarro/math/SmallGroups/g21.2.html) non-cyclic group of order 21.

Comment: Are you assuming that any group of order 21 is Abelian? If not then we can construct a counter example by taking the direct product of one such non Abelian group with Z_2.

Comment: As others have said, the statement you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: It seems to me that the case where $n_3=7$ is where the discussed counterexample occurs. And in the case $n_3=1$, $H=S(7)S(3)\cong S(7)\times S(3)$.